# postgresql LISTENER gets no asynchronous notification when NOTIFY is from a different pgconnection in java

Tags: java, notifications

I am using PostgreSQL DB and applying it's LISTEN/NOTIFY functionality. So my listener is at my application server and I have triggers configured on DB such that when NOTIFY operations are performed a NOTIFY message is sent on java server.
However whatever message I notified on db, my application server side always remained quietly.
So I figured that the LISTEN/NOTIFY goes down under the situation of two distinct db connections(one for the notifier, and another for the listener).

Here's my code.

```
big_gp_admin=> NOTIFY change_data_capture, 'test msg from DB';
NOTIFY
Asynchronous notification "change_data_capture" with payload "test msg from DB" received from serve
```

```
        PGDataSource dataSource = new PGDataSource();
        dataSource.setHost("host");
        dataSource.setPort(5432);
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("dbName");
        dataSource.setUser("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pwd");
        
        try (PGConnection connection = (PGConnection) dataSource.getConnection()) {

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.execute("LISTEN change_data_capture");

            PGNotificationListener listener = new PGNotificationListener() {
                @Override
                public void notification(int processId, String channelName, String payload) {
                    PGNotificationListener.super.notification(processId, channelName, payload);
                    System.out.println("Received Notification: " + processId + ", " + channelName + ", " + payload);

                }
            };

            connection.addNotificationListener(listener);
            statement.execute(" NOTIFY change_data_capture, 'test msg from java code'");

            statement.close();
            while (true) {
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

To do a more specific test in java, I created two distinct connections, one for the notifier
and another for the listener to test if the communication would work across connections and it didn't.

```
public class NotificationTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "url";

        // Create two distinct connections, one for the notifier
        // and another for the listener to show the communication
        // works across connections although this example would
        // work fine with just one connection.
        Connection lConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pwd");
        Connection nConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pwd");

        // Create two threads, one to issue notifications and
        // the other to receive them.
        Notifier notifier = new Notifier(nConn);
        Listener listener = new Listener(lConn);
        listener.start();
        notifier.start();
    }
}

class Listener extends Thread {
    private Connection conn;
    private org.postgresql.PGConnection pgconn;

    Listener(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        this.conn = conn;
        this.pgconn = conn.unwrap(org.postgresql.PGConnection.class);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("LISTEN mymessage");
        stmt.close();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                org.postgresql.PGNotification notifications[] = pgconn.getNotifications();

                // If this thread is the only one that uses the connection, a timeout can be used to
                // receive notifications immediately:
                // org.postgresql.PGNotification notifications[] = pgconn.getNotifications(10000);

                if (notifications != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < notifications.length; i++)
                        System.out.println("Got notification: " + notifications[i].getName());
                }

                // wait a while before checking again for new
                // notifications

                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Notifier extends Thread {
    private Connection conn;

    public Notifier(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("NOTIFY mymessage, 'tetsestest'");
                stmt.close();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                sqle.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Could you kindly indicate which part of my code is causing the problem? Thanks so much.